# CodeIgniter Query Results Only Displays Last Row in View

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, templates, foreach

I want to display a list of results from my database. Currently, my view is only displaying the last row my query retrieves. What am I missing here? Thanks for any help you can give.

Model:

```
public function get_agencies() {
    $this->db->select("AgencyNumber, AgencyName, users.id, active");
    $this->db->from('Agency, users');
    $this->db->where('users.id = Agency.id');
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($q->result() as $agency) {
            $data['agencies'] = $agency;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function modify_agency() {
    $this->load->model('ion_auth_model');
    $this->data['agencies'] = $this->ion_auth_model->get_agencies();

    //added the following 2 lines to load view with header and footer from template         
    $this->data['main_content'] = 'auth/modify_agency';
    $this->load->view('./includes/template', $this->data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($agencies as $agency):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $agency->AgencyNumber;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $agency->AgencyName;?></td>
        <td><?php if($agency->active == 1) { echo 'Active'; } else { echo 'Inactive'; };?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like that.

```
$data[] = $agency;
```

You don't need to parse the the value agencies.CodeIgniter do it for you

```
$data['agencies'] = $agency;
```

Try it.

Comment: Excellent! I updated my model to `$data[] = $agency;` and my full results are now displaying. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your model, you're not pushing the `$agency` variable into an array. They're getting replaced on every iteration and hence `$data['agencies']` will only contain the value of the last iteration. Also, as Syed answered above, you don't need to include the array index value in your code

Change it to:

```
$data[] = $agency;
```

or:

```
array_push($data, $agency);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes sense, but still having issues. In my model, I updated `$data['agencies'] = $agency;` to `$data['agencies'][] = $agency;`. Now receiving PHP errors from my view - "Trying to get property of non object".

Comment: @user1337595: Glad to know you got it working. Anyway, i've updated this answer for the sake of correctness. Cheers! :)

Comment: ok let me run your logic you have users and data about users and you want to show the data with specific user isn'it

Comment: @syedshah: Huh? Your answer is already accepted. Also, I think you're commenting on the wrong thread ;)

Comment: Yup sorry @AmalMurali

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
(...)
$this->data['agencies'] = $this->ion_auth_model->get_agencies();
(...)
$this->load->view('./includes/template', $this->data);
(...)
```

Model:

```
(...)
if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($q->result() as $agency) {
        $data['agencies'] = $agency;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($agencies as $agency):?>
(...)
```

Note that if there isn't a single row as result in your get_agencies you are not returning anything, and you'll receive an error in your foreach function in the view.

And you can return like this:

```
public function get_agencies() {
    $this->db->select("AgencyNumber, AgencyName, users.id, active");
    $this->db->from('Agency, users');
    $this->db->where('users.id = Agency.id');
    $q = $this->db->get();

    return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result() : array();
}
```